# Phonegap Cordova with PDFjs securtiy policy error

Tags: android, cordova, pdf, phonegap-plugins, pdf.js

I'm working with Adobe PhoneGap 6.3.3, I'm trying to display a PDF in a hybrid android app with PFDjs. In browser the pdf is diplayed, insted from mobile with PhoneGap App Develover it doesn't work. In console I have this message:

```
Content Security Policy has been modified to be: <meta
 http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'un
safe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com * ws:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data
: blob:;media-src *;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

I read the pdf from internet with following code:

```
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/foo.pdf';
    getBinaryData(url); //call this fn on page load 

    var callGetDocument = function (response) {
          // body...
          PDFJS.getDocument(response).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
            console.log('File caricato');
            pdfFile = _pdfDoc;
            openPage(pdfFile, currPageNumber, 1);

          });
        }


    var getBinaryData = function (url) {
        console.log('getBinaryData');
        // body...
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            //binary form of ajax response,
            callGetDocument(e.currentTarget.response);
        };

        xhr.onerror = function  () {
            // body...
            console.log("xhr error");
        }

        xhr.send();
    }
```

I still insert `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />`in `config.xml`.
Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9043260#9043260)

It was a CSP (content-security-policy) issue.
From [this](http://cspisawesome.com/) site I created a CSP, and I inserted the meta tag in my `index.html`